# ChangeNotifierProxyProvider getting null value

Tags: flutter, null, flutter-change-notifier

I am new to flutter.

In my application locale information is found when the user login.
So the idea is when the user login, it will pass the locale to AppLanguage.

I have written ChangeNotifierProxyProvider to get the locale inside authentication information and create a AppLanuage object

In the ChangeNotifierProxyProvider I am getting appLang as null. auth object is correctly NOT null.

What I don't understand why I am getting null?

I did create it here right?

```
create: (_) => AppLanguage(),
```

shouldn't it come as a parameter for the update?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: Auth()),
        ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, AppLanguage>(
            create: (_) => AppLanguage(),
            update: (ctx, auth, appLang) {
              print(auth);
              print(appLang);
            }
            //appLang.setLocale(auth == null ? 'en' : auth.language),
            ),
      ],
      child: Consumer2<Auth, AppLanguage>(
        builder: (ctx, auth, lang, child) => MaterialApp(
          title: 'Test App',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
          ),
          locale: lang.appLocal,
          supportedLocales: [
            const Locale('en', 'US'),
            const Locale('ja', ''),
          ],
          localizationsDelegates: [
            AppLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
          ],
          home: LandingView(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try something like:

```
ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, AppLanguage>(
  create: (_) => AppLanguage(),
  update: (ctx, auth, appLang) => appLang..update(auth),
),
```

```
class AppLanguage with ChangeNotifier {
  void update(Auth auth) {
    // Do some custom work based on myModel that may call `notifyListeners`
  }
}
```

That way your child will be able to get the correct updated values when they're available.

You can check more how to deal properly with that on the [provider docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/ChangeNotifierProxyProvider-class.html).

Comment: what does double dots in "appLang..update(auth)" do?

Comment: returns the `appLang` model with new values accordingly to the new `auth`  value